# Create registry key without creating a value using Inno Setup

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I'm struggling with Inno Setup which compared to WiX does not have a RegistryKey element. How could I create a reg key without inserting a value in it? I guess it's something very basic that I'm missing here...

This is the way I create a value:

```
 Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters";  ValueName: "SMBDeviceEnabled";  ValueType: dword; ValueData: 00000000; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it...
Do not include `ValueName`, `ValueType` and `ValueData` properties and it's a key only.

[Registry section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection)